VSCode suggestions are blank
I'm having trouble with the auto-complete suggestions in Visual Studio Code. They've suddenly stopped working, even though they were functioning properly before. I've tried adjusting various settings but haven't been able to resolve the issue.

**Specifics:**

* I'm using Visual Studio Code version 1.95.1 on windows 10
* The auto-complete suggestions for all languages (e.g., Python, JavaScript, etc.) are not working.
* I've tried restarting VS Code and my computer, but the problem persists.

**Troubleshooting Steps I've Taken:**

* Checked the `editor.quickSuggestions` setting and ensured it's enabled.
* Disabled and re-enabled extensions related to language support or IntelliSense.
* Tried reinstalling extensions.
* Verified that language extensions are installed and enabled.

**Any suggestions or troubleshooting tips would be greatly appreciated.**



You can try checking VS Code logs. They should be located at the bottom in a tab called OUTPUT. Perhaps an extension is acting up or something else is misconfigured.
Here is a short manual: https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/application-integration/adapter-builder/view-vs-code-extension-logs.html
